# How to sort a DataTable excepting rows that meet a condition?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I'm trying to sort in a certain order a `DataTable` in C#, the special thing about it, is that I need that some rows remain in the original position if meet a given condition.

Im currently using this function:

`OriginalTable.DefaultView.Sort = "[column_name] ASC";`

The `OriginalTable` include rows with no data, I need those rows to stay, while the other ones being sorted by ASC condition. Any ideas that might help to solve this?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: What's the condition? Have you tried using `UNION` from the SQL query?

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer, did you mean using DataTable.select?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the structure. And I am sure there is no direct way to fulfil your requirement. Just trying to give pointers/ pseudo-code here.

```
Step 1: Create a dictionary(Key-value) for the rows which met your condition. Ensure to keep the index of the item in the key
Step 2: Create a list with rows which do not met your condition. Then sort it
Step 3: Insert the rows from step 2 into your datatable one by one checking the index. If you find the index in step 1 rows, insert it at that location
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this is the closer way to do it within specific function.